# C# SDK for videocalls

Tags: c#, video-conferencing, sdk

I'm looking for a SDK to develop a video call application in .NET (C#). I prefer an Open Source solution, but I'm evaluating also non free solutions. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/video-conferencing) for this. This SDK includes support for standard streams such as RTSP and MPEG-2 Transport over UDP. LEADTOOLS also provides a proprietary stream specific for video conferencing applications with dedicated demos to illustrate this.

You can set up a simple server and client in just a few lines of code. Here's sample server code:

```
CaptureCtrl _capturectrl = new CaptureCtrl();
_capturectrl.VideoDevices[0].Selected = true;
_capturectrl.AudioDevices[0].Selected = true;
_capturectrl.VideoCompressors.H264.Selected = true;
_capturectrl.AudioCompressors.AAC.Selected = true;

_capturectrl.TargetFormat = TargetFormatType.NET;
_capturectrl.TargetFile = @"ltsf://127.0.0.1:27027"; //set up port to listen for connections

_capturectrl.StartCapture(CaptureMode.VideoAndAudio);
```

Here's sample client code:

```
PlayCtrl _playctrl = new PlayCtrl();
this.Controls.Add(_playctrl);
_playctrl.SourceFile = @"ltsf://127.0.0.1:27027"; //Set port to sent connection request to
_playctrl.Run();
```

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.